# How can I put my input underneath the correct column and besides the correct row?

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, matrix, coordinates

this is my code for my two dimensional table.

What I want to do is that I put my input on the correct spot - But as you can see, my output of the table is not as it should be. The columns are overlapping the rows. 
My question is: How can I put columns a bit more to the right. And also - how can i get my input on the correct position ?

Some tips and help are appreciated.

```
        string[,] clubs = new string[20, 30];
        clubs[1, 0] = "     ADO";
        clubs[2, 0] = "     Ajax";
        clubs[3, 0] = "     AZ";
        clubs[4, 0] = "     FC-GR";
        clubs[5, 0] = "     FC-TW";
        clubs[6, 0] = "     FC-U";
        clubs[7, 0] = "     FEY";
        clubs[8, 0] = "     HER";
        clubs[9, 0] = "     NAC";
        clubs[10, 0] = "     NEC";
        clubs[11, 0] = "     PSV";
        clubs[12, 0] = "     RKC";
        clubs[13, 0] = "     ROD";
        clubs[14, 0] = "     SC";
        clubs[15, 0] = "    SPA";
        clubs[16, 0] = "     VIT";
        clubs[17, 0] = "     VVV";
        clubs[18, 0] = "     WIL";


        clubs[0, 1] = "Ado Den haag";
        clubs[0, 2] = "Ajax";
        clubs[0, 3] = "AZ";
        clubs[0, 4] = "FC Groningen";
        clubs[0, 5] = "FC Twente";
        clubs[0, 6] = "FC Utrecht";
        clubs[0, 7] = "Feyenoord";
        clubs[0, 8] = "Hercules Almelo";
        clubs[0, 9] = "NAC Breda";
        clubs[0, 10] = "NEC";
        clubs[0, 11] = "PSV";
        clubs[0, 12] = "RKC Waalwijk";
        clubs[0, 13] = "Roda JC";
        clubs[0, 14] = "SC Heerenveen";
        clubs[0, 15] = "Sparta Rotterdam";
        clubs[0, 16] = "Vitesse";
        clubs[0, 17] = "VVV-Venlo";
        clubs[0, 18] = "Willem II";


        int rows = 15;
        int colums = 15;
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        string str;
        int thuisteam;
        int uitteam;

        Console.WriteLine("Selecteer de thuisteam op een nummer");
        for (int i = 1; i < colums; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(clubs[i, 0] + " " + i);
        }
        str = Console.ReadLine();
        thuisteam = Int32.Parse(str);

        Console.WriteLine("Selecteer de uitteam in onderstaande nummer");
        for (int i = 1; i < rows; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(clubs[0, i] + " " + i);
        }
        str = Console.ReadLine();
        uitteam = Int32.Parse(str);

        Console.WriteLine("Schrijf de score of datum van je wedstrijd op");
        str = Console.ReadLine();
        clubs[thuisteam, uitteam] = str;
        Console.WriteLine();


            for (; y < rows; y++)
            {
                for (; x < colums; x++)
                {
                    Console.Write(clubs[x, y] + " ");
                    if (x == (colums - 1))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("");
                        Console.WriteLine("");

                    }
                }
                x = 0;
            }

            Console.ReadLine();




        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Eamon "is this your homework"  - It's sort of Homework - It's actually an little experiment. I am trying to learn how to work with the arrays, with this assigment ( i made for myself, since i like football). And Console Application is all we are working on at my studies.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to set the cursor position within the Console: [Console.SetCursorPosition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.setcursorposition.aspx). Figuring out the x/y position of the cursor should be as simple as counting rows and characters per column.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered generating an html Table rather than a text-table?  This will avoid the issues with alignment (which the browser will compute for you), and won't require a less-than-readable fixed-width font; not to mention the fact that you can do quite a bit fancier formatting.

Comment: I wish i had a choice to do it in html. But I HAVE to do it in console application. Thanks for your answer though.

Answer (score -1):

Raed [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttxecb1c.aspx) and you'll have no problems

Comment: Ah didn't answer my qeustion. Thanks for trying to help though

Comment: I think a down-vote is a bit harsh. If you'd read it properly you would have found the rest of the Cursor methods, one of which is SetCursorPoisition - as per my answer.